# virtual terminal (getty) inaccessible?

Tags: release-loki, system

My issue is that I cannot login on a virtual terminal (getty). So CtlAltF2 does not give me a login prompt. None of the gettys does actually. Only shortly after booting up I can get a prompt but that does not let me login. Under the previous version of eOS this was not a problem. I do not know where to look to fix this, as I am unfamiliar with the systemd setup of recent years

Answer (score 0):

OK, seems to have resolved itself by cycling default runlevels. Still curious then what caused it, but problem solved I guess.